# Accidental brief full throttle on start - any concerns?

Tags: cold-start, engine-load

I've got a 6 Cylinder N/A BMW (N52 - 3.0) engine with 65,000 miles, that has been fully maintained (last oil change was a few weeks ago).

It had been sat for about 10 days, when I got in, started it, and maybe 5 seconds later leaned over to the back seat, and in doing so, accidentally fully-depressed the throttle (for less than a second).

The revs probably hit 5000-6000rpm, but definitely not the limiter (although my toddler in the back said 'motorbike').

Outside temperature was probably 8-9 degrees C.

Should I be worried about any damage? I'm kicking myself because I'm usually so conscious of treating the motor well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that every day and you'll be fine.

There are two kinds of damage over-revving could cause:

Firstly, the mechanical damage caused by too fast rotation speed. The rev limiter protects against that. So it doesn't matter whether or not you hit the rev limiter as long as the rev limiter is working fine.

Secondly, the accelerated wear. If you do that every day after cold start, it's bad. The clearances of a cold engine will be different than a hot engine and the cold oil doesn't lubricate well. But, do it once and the wear doesn't accumulate too much.